# neo4j returns a Neo4j::Core::Node in test env and the correct subclassed ActiveNode in development

Tags: neo4j.rb

This code

```
@organization = Organization.find(params[:organization_id])
```

returns a `Neo4j::Core::Node` instance in test env and the correct `Organization` instance in development. I am running two servers with this `neo4j.yml`:

```
development:
  type: bolt
  url: bolt://localhost:7687

test:
  type: bolt
  url: bolt://localhost:8687
```

I have `neo4j 8.0.11`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had not added the options `wrap_level: :proc` when setting up the neo4j session adapter for my test environment.

```
def create_server_session
  pn = Pathname.new(__dir__).join('..','..','config','neo4j.yml')
  config_url = YAML.load_file(pn)[Rails.env]['url']
  session_adaptor = Neo4j::Core::CypherSession::Adaptors::Bolt.new(config_url, wrap_level: :proc)
  session = Neo4j::Core::CypherSession.new(session_adaptor)
  Neo4j::ActiveBase.current_session = session
end

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    create_server_session
    delete_db
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this!  I plan to fix this in the near future so that it's automatic if you are using the `neo4j` gem.  I'll update here when that happens

Comment: FYI I just released version `8.0.12` of the `neo4j` gem.  This should automatically set the `wrap_level` on sessions when you use `ActiveNode` / `ActiveRel`

Comment: Thanks very much Brian.